# Is there anyway to fire MouseEvents for the control inside the panel with IsHitTestVisible false

Tags: silverlight

Is there anyway to fire MouseEvents for the control inside the panel (thirdGrid) with IsHitTestVisible false. I have loaded button inside panel with IsHitTestVisible to false. But i want Button to fire its Mouse events. Is there any workaround i can use to achieve this? If i set thirdGrid's IsHitTestVisible to true, then Mouse events is not firing for my firstGrid.

```
<Grid Background="AliceBlue" x:Name="firstGrid" MouseLeftButtonUp="Grid_MouseLeftButtonUp"/>

<Grid Background="AliceBlue" x:Name="secondGrid" IsHitTestVisible="False"/>

<!--Event won't fire for this control since i'm setting IsHitTestVisible to false-->
<Grid x:Name="thirdGrid" IsHitTestVisible="False">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <!--Is there anyway to make this button to fire its events, even if i set its panles IsHitTestVisible to false-->
    <Button Content="click"  Width="150" Height="30" 
        MouseLeftButtonDown="Button_MouseLeftButtonDown"
            IsHitTestVisible="True" />
</Grid>
```

Answer (score 0):

Take the button out of the grid where hit test is false.  Then position it using margins.  If you try the below, it will center it on the screen, and both events will fire.

```
<Grid>
<Grid Background="AliceBlue"
      x:Name="firstGrid"
      MouseLeftButtonUp="Grid_MouseLeftButtonUp" />
<Grid Background="AliceBlue"
      x:Name="secondGrid"
      IsHitTestVisible="False" />
<!--Event won't fire for this control since i'm setting IsHitTestVisible to false-->
<Grid x:Name="thirdGrid"
      IsHitTestVisible="False">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
        <RowDefinition Height="*" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <!--Is there anyway to make this button to fire its events, even if i set its panles IsHitTestVisible to false-->

</Grid>
     <Button Content="click"
            Width="150"
            Height="30"
            Click="ButtonBase_OnClick"
             />
</Grid>
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. Now i have edited my questions based on my actual requirement. If i do as you mentioned, Events for firstGrid is not firing.